# I am getting (sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input) error in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is the code that I used:

```
def edit():

    global editor
    editor = Toplevel()
    editor.title("Edit A Record")  
    editor.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\StePHAnie\Desktop\Python course (learning python)\Tkinter full course in python\icon.ico")
    editor.geometry("360x550")

    conn = sqlite3.connect("address_book.db") 
    c = conn.cursor() 

    record_id = delete_box.get()                   
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + record_id)
    records = c.fetchall()
```

and this is an error that I am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StePHAnie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\StePHAnie\Desktop\Python course (learning python)\VScode\Tkinter\complenation_notes_tkinter_python3.py", line 463, in edit
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = " + record_id)  # and add here (WHERE oid = " + (the name of delete_box.get here it is record_id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

I tried doing everything I can but I couldn't figure out the solution.
By the way, I spent two days trying to get any solution to this

[Go to this link to see a picture of the code with an error in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMErB.png)

If anybody can help me please do.

Comment: Use: `c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = ?",(record_id,))`

Comment: error shows you in which line you have problem - so first you can  use `print()` to check what you get in variables in this line. Check `print( record_id )`. If you get empty string then SQL query will be incomplete. And later you can try to figure out why `delete_box.get()` give empty string. Maybe you get `record_id` from  wrong widget. Or maybe you use GUI in wrong way - you doesn't wait for data in widget (wery common mistake when someone expect that widgets will works like `input()`).

Comment: Thanks, Cool Cloud for replying to my question but bro                                                                           but bro `code` c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE oid = ?"(record_id,))                                                                                                                                                                                     showing the same problem I mean it is not the same error and it is running the code correctly but not as I want it to run